# Passing output from R to php

Tags: php, r

So I am trying to use php to run an R code that just adds 3 inputted numbers together and returns the results to php. The php R connection works and will print results to my website if I include a print statement in my R code, however I want to store the output results in a variable $output. When I used this exec statement nothing gets stored into $output. Thanks for the help

R CODE:

```
args = commandArgs(TRUE)
file1 = as.numeric(args[1])
file2 = as.numeric(args[2])
file3 = as.numeric(args[3])

output = file1+file2+file3
ans2 = data.frame(output)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "g1076652", password = "******", dbname = "g1076652", host = "mydb.ics.purdue.edu")
on.exit(dbDisconnect(mydb))

dbWriteTable(mydb,value=ans2,name="Test",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
exec("Rscript testwebsite.R $file1 $file2 $file3", $output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Umm, your code snippet is a png. Why?

Comment: Use: exec("Rscript testwebsite.R $file1 $file2 $file3  2>&1", $output, $return_var);

Comment: So I tried that and it still gives output as 0. I am wondering if there is a problem on the R end, I attached a screenshot of my code if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me, I have exactly 10 minutes of PHP experience, but this seems to work

```
<?php
$a = 2;
$b = 3;
$c = 4;
$arr = array($a, $b, $c);
$sum = array_sum($arr);
echo "sum(arr) = " . $sum . "\n";
?>

sum(arr) = 9
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJVHBVsHImkslCUgbA@lkIG0CpBOLioAsIJlYqaGSqKOgkgTEyZpAmeLSXJhMPJCtAVIKFE9NzshXUAIJgPhAFUoKegpgxXoKSjF5StZc9nb//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super experienced with R, but I don't see you outputting anything from the R script.

As well, `$output` is an array here, and will need to be converted from an array into a string before using `echo()` on it.

Note if you're only expecting a single line of output, the return value of `exec()` is the last line output as a string.

```
<?php
$lastline = exec("Rscript testwebsite.R $file1 $file2 $file3", $full_output, $return_status);
// we can just echo the last line, it's a string:
echo "$lastline\n";
// but the full output is an array
echo implode("\n", $full_output);
// and the return status should be zero, otherwise the R script failed
echo $return_status;
```

Comment: And I'm assuming your actual R script is more complicated than this, otherwise you'd save a lot of hassle just doing the whole thing in PHP.